Was I right to insist I be listed as a co-author if my contribution was to be included?
I've done most of my research during my Mathematics PhD with a single collaborator who is not my advisor. He has definitely served as a mentor and has been something of an unofficial advisor - even though he is at another institution. I started working with him at a period when things were not working out with my advisor and I needed someone to do research with. He can be demanding and our relationship has been something of a stressor - but overall he was good to work with. As time has gone on, the dynamic has shifted towards one where I am making the primary intellectual contributions and he is tagging along.
Last week he told me that he was resubmitting a paper he wrote with a different co-author. He said that for one of the responses it would be useful to use a technique I developed and had shared with him in an Overleaf a year ago and asked whether I'd be willing to write that up for him.
I assumed that by writing this section, I would be added as a co-author to the paper.
The section contained some ideas that I developed which I was hoping to save for future work. Overall this was a pretty small contribution and I wouldn't say this technique is the most important thing I developed during my PhD.
Nevertheless, I was distressed to find that I was only put in the acknowledgements. I raised the issue with him over email and he became genuinely furious. We had a very tense conversation over the phone. Among other things, he repeatedly raised the idea that I am not appropriately "respecting the lines of authority" and that I should essentially just be quiet and accept his judgement on this matter.
He’d probably say that he feels I’m not appreciating the time he’s put in to my collaboration with him, that he has vouched for me in the past, that he adapted and amended the ideas I shared, and that he had suggested the line of work that led to these ideas.
About those last two points  while it is true that these ideas I had developed came out of my thoughts on a paper he suggested I read, I personally don’t feel that is enough to justify taking credit for those ideas. He presented a very slight generalization of the ideas I gave and a slightly edited version of the proof I wrote which took about two weeks to formulate when I came up with it last year.
I’m very distressed. While I don’t consider this set of ideas to be crucial to my PhD work, I was very proud of them. But at the same time, perhaps I don’t understand how things work in academia and I should “respect the lines of authority” – to use his phrase.
I asked that he remove my contributions from the paper. He obliged but indicated that this was the end of our professional relationship, that I should be more grateful to him for his efforts in our collaboration, and that I need to learn humility.
Am I sounding unreasonable? Is this just how things work? I would hate to be inappropriate and I appreciate that he’s been a good collaborator but I also feel I should stand up for my academic integrity.
He seemed to have a lot of bottled anger and I wonder if he is annoyed that I'm leaving academia after he's put time in to mentor me with the hopes I'd be a productive collaborator. In our call he went on for some time about how "ridiculous" it was that I was taking time off of research to focus on getting a job in industry.
He's taking his sabbatical to work at this research institute - so I'm wondering if he's also annoyed that I'm not helping him further his career by making the most of this research year.

‘ he went on for some time about how "ridiculous" it was that I was taking time off of research to focus on getting a job in industry.’ Sounds a bit unhinged to me.

What country is this? “[r]espect the lines of authority” is BS anywhere, but how deep a pile might depend on how much the local academic culture cares about hierarchies.

https://fastdecals.com/shop/images/detailed/30/cartman-respect-ma-authoritah-decal-sicker-06_southparkFC-1.webp

Your collaborator's behaviour is completely inappropriate and could be classed as misconduct. You did nothing wrong. If you're an author then you must be listed as an author, and if you wrote a section of the paper then you are an author. There isn't any possible ambiguity about it.

Whether you're right or wrong, reading your post does make me wonder whether you made your point in a manner which was less than optimal considering your different positions and history.

The culture around coauthorship in mathematics is typically very generous. Regardless of the outcome here, I find his attitude unusual.

What “respect the lines of authority” really means is "I refuse to discuss this, go away".  Totally inappropriate behaviour and could possibly be classed as bullying.

When you do get a job in industry, I believe you'll look back at this and think clearly: "wow, that guys was way out of line."

In general, the rule for who should be an author on a paper is whether they have made a "significant contribution" to the paper. From what you've written here, it sounds like your former collaborator wanted to use an unpublished technique you came up with, and even had you write-up that technique. It is entirely reasonable, based on this description of events, to want authorship on the paper this technique is first presented in. (If you had previously published the technique, it would perhaps be more appropriate for that publication to be cited rather than adding you as an author, but that is a different debate.)
What he has done for you/the paper doesn't matter for the question of whether YOU should be an author. It doesn't matter if he put a lot of time and effort into mentoring you, if he pointed out the paper you read that inspired the idea for your technique, etc. Those have nothing to do with whether YOU should be an author on a paper. All that matters for that question is what YOU have contributed to the paper.

appreciate that he’s been a good collaborator

Good collaborators don't play authorship games with grad students. (Or anyone else, for that matter.)

I honestly don't understand this. Granted, I come from a different field (biology) and we only have your side of the story, but from what I read, you actually wrote a section of the paper. Your words are included in the paper. That is precisely the definition of "author".
This is beyond the normal academic squabbling of whether or not your contribution was significant; you have actually written a section of the paper yourself, so you authored that section and since that section is part of the paper, you authored part of the paper and should therefore be included in the list of people named as authors.
Unless this "section" was only a couple of words buried in supplementary data, you are an author under any definition of the term I can think of. As for respecting the lines of authority, that feels like pure nonsense. You are a grad student, you are not a child. You are a working adult and this was your work. What authority? This person is a collaborator, so isn't even your supervisor. There is no authority here.
So no, unless there is much more to it that you aren't sharing (or aren't aware of), you're fine and their behavior is not OK.

It may be that the "mentor" realizes they are at high risk for an accusation of academic misconduct and their lashing out is intended to discourage reporting that behavior (or a less controlled behavioral vomit of their fears).

This is all true but I would say there is no need to add the qualifier "Unless the section was buried in supplementary data" because I don't see any reason to distinguish between the main text and supplementary material when it comes to authorship. They are both part of the publication.

Oh, sure, @qdread, I am just saying that maaaaayyybe if it was "a couple of words", then it might be OK not to be an author. having it in supmat just makes it a little easier to say it isn't part of it, but the main point is that I could understand not giving authorship only if the authored text was really, really small.

I agree that someone who does the work and writes it up should probably be an author. I disagree with the implication that simply writing any part of the paper warrants authorship - an academic writing consultant or editor, for example, should likely not be an author. Drafting the work is just one of the multiple usual criteria for authorship. An academic author is generally not defined as "anyone who wrote part of the paper". OP should be an author because of their contributions, not just for what they wrote.

@NuclearHoagie yes, you can be an author without having written anything. However, if you have "written a section" of the paper, I can't imagine how you could not be an author.  Editors aren't writers, they edit and adapt someone else's work. In any case, this isn't about editors or writing consultants, so I don't really see how they're relevant.

@terdon I think the distinction NuclearHoagie is making is an important one. The context provided in this answer makes it clear to me that you're referring to someone writing a whole section, but some may take the line 'your words are included in the paper. That is precisely the definition of "author"' at face value and think "I wrote a few sentences to clarify a point in the background section and I should thus be an author."

@WhatTheDuck I mean, OK, I guess some people might, but I don't really see why I should cater to folks who don't read the entirety of what really is a pretty short answer. If they just glance at a partial phrase and form an opinion, there's not much I can do.

@terdon Many users here do not read/speak English as their first language, so there's nothing wrong with clarifying these points in the comments. As I said, while I, personally, understood exactly what you were saying, there is a non-zero chance that some first year student will see "your words are included in the paper" not as you emphasizing how ridiculous it is that the collaborator here would even think there's an argument to exclude msm from the author list, but as a statement implying that "if you wrote [any] words that appear in the paper, you are an author."

I would disagree that writing a section of the text should automatically imply authorship, especially if this text was edited later by others. Text is a rather insignificant part of research, and nowadays even AI can write text. What is much more important is the idea behind, data, methodology, and so on. If this was a novel or newspaper article, text would be the central contribution.

The authorship criteria changes from field to field. In my pure math experience, proving a proposition which takes 1 page out of 30 doesn't grant the authorship but a gratitude in the acknowledgment section. I know that in other fields you can hang out in the same lab as your PI, conduct experiment and be a coauthor without writing up much.

Can everyone please stop discussing whether or not the general idea of having written text is enough? Please take it to char or comment on the OP. I am not making any general points here and the barrage of comments is getting tiresome.

First of all: the entire situation seems quite a mess; more about this towards the end of this answer.
Yet, given the somewhat limited information in the original post, I'm surprised by the very clear stance that some of the other answers take on the situation.
Contributions and authorship in mathematics
It is certainly not true that contributing a technique or insight or result or proof is always considered to warrant co-authorship in mathematics. One can frequently read passages in math papers that say something like "We are grateful to John Doe for providing us with a proof of Theorem 3.5" or "We are indepted to Jane Doe for communicating Counterexample 4.3 to us (private communication)".
Like WhatTheDuck says in their answer, the crucial question is how "significant" OP's contribution was. But in contrast to WhatTheDuck I find it impossible to determine this from the information given in the question. The main reason why I find this impossible is that significance is highly context-dependent. It's very easy to imagine two different papers A and B of similar quality und relevance and a theorem which would be a very significant contribution in paper A but only a nice-to-have in paper B.
One thing to keep in mind here is that authors are listed alphabetically in papers in (pure) mathematics. There is no concept of a "first author" or "main author".
So if, say, mathematician A develops a deep and lengthy theory in a paper and mathematician B proves a theorem for the paper which provides some additional context but which is in no way essential for the theory, then adding B as a co-author would strongly misrepresent the contributions of A and B. In this case it is very common that A is the sole author and only thanks B somewhere in the paper.
From the description in the question it seems impossible to say how significant OP's contribution was in the context of this paper. So I don't think we can judge whether OP was right to insist on being a co-author.
Two more comments:

Whether OP has written the section themselve is irrelevant for the question (although I find it quite weird that the colleague explicitly asked OP to do the writing).
(By the way, most likely it will actually be quite difficult - even for the OP and their colleague - to clearly determine how much of the section was written by the OP, since the colleague apparently made some adjustments. Moreover, it's not even clear what precisely "writing" means in the context of writing a paper.)

Even knowing the degree of novelty of the techique developed by the OP would not suffice to judge how significant OP's contribution was. It is absolutely possible to use a highly novel and innovative technique to make a contribution to a paper which adds, for this paper, only minor or peripheral insights.
(The technique might of course still be of very significant use in another paper.)


All this said, let me stress again that I'm not saying that OP doesn't deserve authorship in this situation. I'm merely saying that, given the information in the question, it is impossible to judge whether or how much OP deserves to be an author in this situation.
Social aspects
Much more worrisome than the authorship question at hand, is, from my perspective, how the situation evolved at a social level. Person A believing that they should be a co-author while person B disagrees is one thing - but going from there to a full-grown argument, summoning "lines of authority" and the like is something very different.
General advice
I think we can't say whether OP was right to insist to be listed as a co-author. I'm also not sure we can give good advice regarding OP's relationship with their colleague, as their seems to be a lot of frustration involved (possibly on both sides) and we don't know much about the background.
Yet, there is one generic piece of advice which works, in my experience, quite well when it comes to authorship in mathematics (and a lot of mathematicians seems to follow it, be it consciously or only intuitively):

Put the bar of what constitutes a "significant contribution" quite high when it comes to the question whether you should be a co-author somewhere.

Put the bar much lower when it comes to the question whether someone else should be a co-author of one of your papers.


When mathematicians interact who follow those guidelines, it regularly comes to situations where someone suggests to "remove my name from the paper because I have not contributed enough to be an author" or where someone says "I think you should be a co-author of this paper" and the other person replies "probably not". Obviously, those disagreements are much easier and much more pleasant to resolve than the one described by in the question.

It might be appropriate in this situation for the section written by the OP to be included with the original paper as an Appendix, to which the OP would be one of the authors (or even the sole author), without the OP being an author of the paper itself.

I agree that ultimately the authorship issue is a bit blurry, but the truth is I'm far more distressed about the social aspect of the situation. When he and I talked on the phone, he seemed to be far angrier that I was not obeying his authority than that I was uncomfortable with his using my material in the paper. A few of the particular things that really distressed me were "I spent time on you on the assumption you would work nonstop on math problems. I want these problems solved. And now you're doing this job search and I'll have to start all over again with someone else"

Some context might be helpful. My collaborator -M -has a co-author on this paper- T. I have a joint paper with M and T.  I was confused about this issue yesterday partly because T has not even read that joint paper. He was involved in the early discussions and will be involved in follow ups. That paper consisted entirely of work I did. M wrote about a third of the exposition but I developed the results, wrote all the proofs, and implemented all the numerics. In that case I felt that was okay because they'd had the initial idea and I was just lucky enough to have all the crucial insights.

(This will be my last comment - I apologize for the extended add on.) Ultimately, this is somewhat less about the authorship and more about the power dynamics. My title is perhaps emphatic. I didn't truly insist I be listed as an author. I raised that I would not have agreed to have the material incorporated had I known I would not be listed as an author. He said yesterday "I am the authority figure, you should be accepting my judgement on this matter." I felt it was inappropriate for him to wield  his position of authority in the discussion of whether or not I deserved credit.

@msm This is indeed an unsettling dynamic. Where has the anger come from? Well I certainly can't say because I am not that person, but I can tell you that your particular situation is not a great scenario. You were essentially using this person as an advisor. However, he can never claim you as a pupil, not in terms of justifiable time to his University, or as any measurable product of his career. A couple of papers here and there, really are quite meaningless once you get to a certain point, and the value becomes your legacy in academia. So you are leaving academia, and his time was wasted...

@msm continued... Is this reason to get angry? Certainly not, that was always going to be the most likely scenario since few people make it to academia, so any anger and frustration in that regard is of his making. We are all responsible for our own emotions. What can you do? Probably nothing, but for others reading this I would really advise against this scenario of severing ties with your advisor only to work with someone else at another institution unofficially.

While it's true that you will occasionally see things like your Doe examples in math papers, in these cases J. Doe will have freely offered the suggestion for inclusion in the paper with no expectation of authorship. OP's case is quite different: their contribution was requested.

@EspeciallyLime: Well, it depends. I remember some occasions where I was able to helped other mathematicians with a specific problem upon their request and the solution made it into an article without me becoming a co-author. It really depends on how significant the contribution is for the substance of the paper.

@msm I think it is useful to consider how things would play out if OP's contribution didn't warrant authorship, but everybody was professional. Authorship is best resolved before the work is done. OP probably should have asked when his work was requested, but the collaborator is more senior and bears responsibility for not setting correct expectations. If misunderstanding arises later, the collaborator should have started discussion, explaining the norms for authorship clearly and ideally (being responsible for the misunderstanding) offer concessions/compensation - even if just symbolic.

Well, I suppose people have different views but I wouldn't consider it reasonable to ask someone to work on a problem for inclusion in my paper unless I thought it was significant.

I am working in physics, where papers typically have 10+ coauthors and adding one more is usually not a big deal. A single author's contribution can be 5% or even less. In our field, someone who wrote some part of the text and contributed some ideas would be definitely considered a co-author. However, in mathematics things are usually different and papers typically have just one or very few authors. When I see a paper that has 2 authors, I would assume their contributions are comparable or at least 2:1 but not 10:1. Say, if a scholar named Smith proves an important theorem, he wants it to become famous as the Smith theorem and not as the Smith et al. theorem. Therefore, keeping that in mind, if I am about to write a single-author paper, I would rather do all the work myself or at least make it clear to someone I ask for help with writing well in advance that they are not going to make it on the author list. In your case it is hard to form an opinion without knowing how many authors there were in total and what were the proportions of their intellectual contributions.

Speaking as a mathematician: the level of contribution OP described should unambiguously result in authorship, even if there was only one other author. This is both the ethical answer and the answer that lines up with the culture of the field.

Yes, it's less than ideal to have a two-author paper where one author's contributions greatly outweigh the other's, but that is less bad than passing off someone else's work as one's own. The professor crossed a bright red line here.

I certainly agree with your arguments, but without hearing from the other side and not knowing how important that contribution was, I don't think a fair judgement is possible. Contributions below a certain level certainly should be reserved for the acknowledgments. I can also think of a situation when the author already had the same ideas that were "shared" with him by the student and was in the process of writing them up. The fact that they were not in a formal student-advisor relationship complicates things somewhat.

I really like Jochen Glueck's answer who is a mathematician but his opinion is different from yours.

"Physics, where papers typically have 10+ coauthors" - this depends on subfield. For instance, my PhD subfield was combustion physics; I do not remember ever seeing a paper with 10+ authors, and I could confirm that memory today (method: take a quick look at the latest issue of a good journal in that niche, result: most papers between 4 and 6 authors, the maximum at 8).

@user1149748: "it's less than ideal to have a two-author paper where one author's contributions greatly outweigh the other's, but that is less bad than passing off someone else's work as one's own." This is a false dichotomy, though. The canonical action in such a situation is to mention the other person's contributions in the acknowledgements, so no one's worked is passed off as somebody else's work. Regarding the red line that you say the authors crossed: apparently they sent the manuscript to the OP before they resubmitted it, so I don't see any bright red line being crossed. [...]

[...] (But as I said in my answer, we cannot know though whether their suggestion to only mention OP in the acknowledgements was appropriate, as this depends on a lot of context information that we don't have. And in any case, the colleague's behaviour later on indeed seems completely out-of-line.)

@JochenGlueck If the contribution were something quite simple, then an acknowledgement might be appropriate, but I'm assuming if that were the case, there'd have been no need for the professor to ask OP to write it up formally. I guess that assumption could be wrong--since this professor is clearly unreasonable, and unreasonable people do surprising things--but I've never heard of someone writing pages of a paper that they weren't an author of. OP uses the word "section" so it doesn't sound like just a paragraph or something.

But yes, ultimately we have only one side of the story and therefore can't speak in absolutes.
